# JSP SQL INSERT formatted incorrectly using Timestamp and prepared statement

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

After searching stackoverflow for people with similar problems, I couldn't find an answer for my specific case. I'm formatting my Timestamp to fit in with how SQL inserts timestamps. I keep getting this error:

**You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'show(theater_id, movie_id, st_time, end_time, lang) values(1,4,'2018-10-297 16:1' at line 1**

```
<%
Driver d = new Driver();
String entryString = "insert into show(theater_id, movie_id, st_time, end_time, lang) values(?,?,?,?,?);";
ArrayList<Object> vals = new ArrayList<Object>();

SimpleDateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");

vals.add(new Integer(1));
vals.add(new Integer(4));
vals.add(date.format(Timestamp.valueOf("2018-10-24 16:10:0")));
vals.add(date.format(Timestamp.valueOf("2018-10-24 18:31:0")));
vals.add("English");

d.entry(entryString, vals);%>

public void entry(String entryString, ArrayList<Object> vals) {
    int i = 1;
    try {
        sql = dbconn.prepareStatement(entryString);
        for(Object o: vals) {
            sql.setObject(i,o);
            i++;
        }
        System.out.println(sql.toString()+"\n"+Arrays.toString(vals.toArray()));
        sql.execute();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Here's what that println spits out, too

```
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement: insert into show(theater_id, movie_id, st_time, end_time, lang) values(1,4,'2018-10-297 16:10:00','2018-10-297 18:31:00','English');
[1, 4, 2018-10-297 16:10:00, 2018-10-297 18:31:00, English]
```

Comment: check this link https://www.guru99.com/insert-into.html

Comment: 'show' is predefine in mysql, if  you used  when throw error.

Comment: does using `backticks` around `show` work?

Answer (score 0):

```
String entryString = "insert into changeShowName(theater_id, movie_id, st_time, end_time, lang) values(?,?,?,?,?);";
```

**SHOW CREATE VIEW** statement is used to show the create view statement. SHOW DATABASES statement is used to lists the databases on the MySQL server host. The SHOW SCHEMAS can be used as a synonym for SHOW DATABASES. If the LIKE clause is present along with the **SHOW DATABASES**, indicates which database names to match.
**Don't be create a show table because show is predefine in mysql.**